# Google PageSpeed Insights with Multiple CSS Files

Tags: javascript, css, pagespeed

I'm optimizing my site based on Google's PageSpeed Insights. It recommends that I "Optimize CSS Delivery" for several files (names simplified for example's sake):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

...by moving them from `<link>` tags in the `<head>` to being called through JavaScript before the closing  tag:

```
<script>
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'css/app.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

`</body>`

As you can see, only `app.css` is being called.

My question is, is there a way to add all three CSS files in this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to extend Google's script so that you can add multiple files like this:

```
var loadCSSFiles = function() {
    var links = ["style1.css", "style2.css", "style3.css"],
        headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
        linkElement, i;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkElement = document.createElement("link");
        linkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
        linkElement.href = links[i];
        headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
    }
};

var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) {
    raf(loadCSSFiles);
} else {
    window.addEventListener("load", loadCSSFiles);
}
```

Comment: Does this thing actually works? because I've done the same an in "PageSpeed Suggestions " section I have the same number of suggestion - more, when i open "PageSpeed Insights" I have even more problems then before doing that.

Only way that actually worked for me was to append a single style with this method above the other that I declare speciffic in head section

Answer (score 0):

If the site is finished and you just need to improve the speed, you can compress all your css files and put them in the head (of course without deleting the originals) you will have at least a 15 points improvement.